# knitr 1.4.1 ending comments in chunk do not display correctly

Tags: r, knitr

I am using knitr 1.4.1 and have observed that when the last line of a chunk (.Rnw file) is a comment, this comment does not display as the previous comments.

Her is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}

<<chunk, echo=TRUE>>=
## comment before output
x <- sum(1:10) ## sum number from 1 to 10
x
(x <- sum(1:10)) ## sum number from 1 to 10
## comment after output
x
## final comment 
@

\end{document}
```

With knitr 1.4.1 all comments but the last one are displayed in italic. As you can see from the LaTeX code below generated when I knit the above chunk, the `\hlcom{}` is missing for the last comment:

```
\begin{knitrout}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.969, 0.969, 0.969}\color{fgcolor}\begin{kframe}
\begin{alltt}
\hlcom{## comment before output}
\hlstd{x} \hlkwb{<-} \hlkwd{sum}\hlstd{(}\hlnum{1}\hlopt{:}\hlnum{10}\hlstd{)}  \hlcom{## sum number from 1 to 10}
\hlstd{x}
\end{alltt}
\begin{verbatim}
## [1] 55
\end{verbatim}
\begin{alltt}
\hlstd{(x} \hlkwb{<-} \hlkwd{sum}\hlstd{(}\hlnum{1}\hlopt{:}\hlnum{10}\hlstd{))}  \hlcom{## sum number from 1 to 10}
\end{alltt}
\begin{verbatim}
## [1] 55
\end{verbatim}
\begin{alltt}
\hlcom{## comment after output}
\hlstd{x}
\end{alltt}
\begin{verbatim}
## [1] 55
\end{verbatim}
\begin{alltt}
## final comment
\end{alltt}
\end{kframe}
\end{knitrout}
```

Any hint on how I could make the last comment look as the other ones would be welcome.

Comment: What command(s) are you using this to convert this? I can't reproduce this by calling `knit()` on your example and then using `pdflatex` to convert to pdf.

Comment: It could also be your PDF viewer messing up. Try another PDF viewer.

Comment: As you can see from the generated LaTeX code (I haved edited the question by inserting it), it is not a PDF problem. The \hlcom{} producing the comment effect is missing for the last comment.

Comment: @Marius The code shown is in a file example.Rnw and use `knit("example.Rnw")`. I am not sure whether the problem occurred with older versions, but I observed the problem just after upgrading to 1.4.1. Are you using this same version of knitr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turns out to be a bug in the [highr](https://github.com/yihui/highr) package, which was due to a bug of `utils::getParseData()` in R 3.0.1. Anyway, I have [fixed it](https://github.com/yihui/highr/commit/a033ac182e34a2c3a4973c8bb2ba86f826c38d4e) in the development version, and for now you can install from RForge.

```
install.packages('highr', repos='http://www.rforge.net/', type='source')
```

This will go to CRAN as highr v0.3 in the future.